# Eventually constant sequence and monotony

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, monotone-functions

If I have an eventually constant sequence, for instance
$x_1=0.9$, $x_2=0.81$, $x_3=0,65$, $x_n=0.5$ $\forall n\geq 4$.

Since the first three terms are decreasing from the first one can I say that $x_n\geq x_{n+1}$ $\forall n\geq 1$ then can I say that the sequence is decreasing, even if from a certain $\bar n$ it becomes constant?

Comment: Yes, the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: Depends on the author. Some use descending for $\ge$ and strictly descending for $>$, others use weakly descending vs. descending, others use non-increasing vs descending for the same distinction

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen For me decreasing means $\geq$ in the inequality and strictly decreasing $>$

Comment: @jin In that case, yes: An eventually constant sequence is decreasing iff it is  decreasing in the initial segment up to when it becomes constant